# C++ Base Class Data Members not getting intialiazed when using virtual inheritance

Tags: c++

[image: Output][image: This is how inheritance works in this program or should be] if i try to access functions of base class like getType,getModel() etc i get no data intiliazed in them
i think their is something else wrong, you can look into last Class bus display option from this i call base function objects which are inherited in it. so these two classes are important base and bus.
if anyone can help me out and guide what im doing wrong, i would be really grateful.
Edit: Picture has been attached, that how inheritance should work in this program

```
    #include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Vehicle{
    private:
        string Type,Make,Model,Color;
        int year;
        float MilesDriven;
    public: 
    Vehicle(){}
        Vehicle(string Type,string Make,string Model,string Color)
        {
            this->Type=Type;
            this->Make=Make;
            this->Model=Model;
            this->Color=Color;
        }
        string getType(){
            return Type;
        }
        string getModel(){
            return Model;
        }
        string getMake(){
            return Make;
        };
        string getColor(){
            return Color;
        }
        int getYear(void){
            return year;
        }
};

class GasVehicle : virtual public Vehicle
{
    private:
        double FuelTankSize;
    public:
        GasVehilce(){}
        GasVehicle(double FuelTankSize,string Type,string Make,string Model,string Color) : Vehicle(Type,Make,Model,Color){ 
            this->FuelTankSize=FuelTankSize;
        }
        double getFuelTankSize(){
            return FuelTankSize;
        }
};

class ElectricVehicle : virtual public Vehicle{
    private:
        string EnergyStorage;
    public:
    ElectricVehicle(string EnergyStorage,string Type,string Make,string Model,string Color) : Vehicle(Type,Make,Model,Color){
        this->EnergyStorage=EnergyStorage;
    }
    string getEnergy(void){
        return EnergyStorage;
    }
};
class HighPerformance : public GasVehicle
{
    private: 
    int horsesPower;
    int TopSpeed;
    public:
    
        HighPerformance(int horsesPower,int Topspeed,int FuelTankSize,string Type,string Make,string Model,string Color) : GasVehicle(FuelTankSize,Type,Make,Model,Color){
            this->horsesPower=horsesPower;
            this->TopSpeed=Topspeed;
        }
};
////
class SportsCar : HighPerformance {
    private:
    
        string GearBox;
        string DriveSystem;
        string RunWheel;
    public:
//          SportsCar(){}
    SportsCar(string GearBox,string DriveSystem,string RunWheel,int horsesPower,int Topspeed,int FuelTankSize,string Type,string Make,string Model,string Color) : HighPerformance(horsesPower,Topspeed,FuelTankSize,Type,Make,Model,Color){
        this->GearBox=GearBox;
        this->DriveSystem=DriveSystem;
        this->RunWheel=RunWheel;
    }
};


class HeavyVehicle : public GasVehicle , public ElectricVehicle
{
    private:
        double MaxiWeight;
        int NumberOfWheels;
        int lenght;
    public:
        HeavyVehicle(int MaxiWeight,int NumberOfWheels,int lenght,double FuelTankSize,string EnergyStorage,string Type,string Make,string Model,string Color) : GasVehicle(FuelTankSize,Type,Make,Model,Color),ElectricVehicle(EnergyStorage,Type,Make,Model,Color){
            this->MaxiWeight=MaxiWeight;
            this->NumberOfWheels=NumberOfWheels;
            this->lenght=lenght;
        }
        double getMaxiWeight(){
            return MaxiWeight;
        }
        int getNumberOfWheels(){
            return NumberOfWheels;
        }
        int getLenght(){
            return lenght;
        }
};//
//
//class ConstractionTrucks : public HeavyVehicle 
//{
//  private:
//  string cargo,cemet,gravel,sand; 
//  public:
//  ConstractionTrucks(string cargo,string cemet,string gravel,string sand,int MaxiWeight,int NumberOfWheels,int lenght,double FuelTankSize,string EnergyStorage,string Type,string Make,string Model,string Color) : HeavyVehicle(MaxiWeight,NumberOfWheels,lenght,FuelTankSize,EnergyStorage,Type,Make,Model,Color)
//  {
//      this->cargo=cargo;
//      this->cemet=cemet;
//      this->gravel=gravel;
//      this->sand=sand;
//  }
//};

class Bus : public HeavyVehicle {
    private:
        int NumberOfseats;
    public:
        Bus(int NumberOfSeats,int MaxiWeight,int NumberOfWheels,string EnergyStorage,int lenght,double FuelTankSize,string Type,string Make,string Model,string Color) : HeavyVehicle(MaxiWeight,NumberOfWheels,lenght,FuelTankSize,EnergyStorage,Type,Make,Model,Color){
            this->NumberOfseats=NumberOfSeats;
        }
        
        void SetNumberOfseats(int seats){
            this->NumberOfseats+=seats;
        }
        int getNumberOfseats(void){
            return NumberOfseats;
        }
        
         void Display(void){
            cout<<"NumbeR Of Seats: "<<getNumberOfseats()<<endl;
            cout<<"MaxiWeight: "<<getMaxiWeight()<<endl;
            cout<<"Number Of wheels: "<<getNumberOfWheels()<<endl;
            cout<<"Lenght: "<<getLenght()<<endl;
            cout<<"FuelTankSize: "<<getFuelTankSize()<<endl;
            cout<<"Type: "<<getType()<<endl;
            cout<<"Model: "<<getModel()<<endl;
        }
    
};

int main(){
    Bus Obj(5,1200.0,8,"Storage",102,304.0,"Metalic","MXS","2001-Suzuzki","White");
    Obj.Display();
}
```

Comment: you want to read about virtual inheritance

Comment: i did used virtual inheritance, let me edit the code wait

Comment: done, now if you run this code, you wont get any erros, but i wont get what type it is or model, i get blank no data saved in variables, thats why i think something else is wrong @463035818_is_not_a_number

Comment: I think you have to separate vehicle class from the type of motor this way a vehicle will have a pointer to the motor which can be of different type (gas, electric...). This make your class design much more simple. My tutor (a long time ago) told me: if you are suing multiple inheritance you are doing something wrong for sure!!!

Comment: @MarcoBeninca this is an assignment and it is compulsory we use inheritance like shown in figure

Comment: But being critical on the design the assigment give you is an added value, isn't it? If something is wrong is wrong... be creative

Comment: i know but thats for real life work project, how you want to do, this on other hand is college work, what teachers want from us, i cant simply modify it like i want :[

Comment: That's a nightmare of an inheritance tree, nobody would ever do that.

Comment: please update the question consistently. The title is now talking about an error that is not present in the code. Include actual and expected output in the question

Comment: you want to read about virtual inheritance ;) With virtual inheritance the most derived object initializes the virtual base. Remove the default constructor of `Vehicle` to get a helpful error message. It shouldnt have a default constructor anyhow, at least not one that leaves members uninitialized

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the virtual inheritance, then the derived class must initialize a virtual base.
this may help you to understand the concept and example. https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/virtual_inheritance.html

Answer (score 1):

The most derived class must initialize a virtual base. Your issue can be illustrated with this:

```
#include <iostream>

struct virtbase {
    int x;
    virtbase(int x) : x(x) {}
    virtbase() : x(42) {}
};

struct middle : virtual virtbase {
    middle(int x) : virtbase(x) {}
};

struct derived : middle {
    derived(int x) : middle(x) {}
};

int main() {
    derived d(1);
    std::cout << d.x;
}
```

[Output is](https://godbolt.org/z/8xor5qsna):

42

I suggest you to try what happens when you [remove the default constructor of `virtbase`](https://godbolt.org/z/q8qWeh5bx). Then there will be an error for missing default constructor of `virtbase` in `derived(int x) : middle(x) {}`. That is becasue the most derived class must initialize the virtual base:

```
#include <iostream>

struct virtbase {
    int x;
    virtbase(int x) : x(x) {}
    virtbase() : x(42) {}
};

struct middle : virtual virtbase {
    middle(int x) : virtbase(x) {}
    middle() {}
};

struct derived : middle {
    derived(int x) : virtbase(x) {}
};

int main() {
    derived d(1);
    std::cout << d.x;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first try was good. Here is an easy solution. You should remove the `virtual` inheritance from `GasVehicle` and `ElectricVehicle`. Now you will get a ambiguous references for `getModel()` and `getType()`. The reason is that `GasVehicle` and `ElectricVehicle` both derive from `Vehicle`. `Bus` now derives from `GasVehicle` and `ElectricVehicle` -- it cannot decide which method should be called. Now it is up to you to tell `Bus` which method it should use. You can do this by resolving the scope.

The `Display` method will look like this:

```
void Display(void)
{
  cout << "NumbeR Of Seats: " << getNumberOfseats() << endl;
  cout << "MaxiWeight: " << getMaxiWeight() << endl;
  cout << "Number Of wheels: " << getNumberOfWheels() << endl;
  cout << "Lenght: " << getLenght() << endl;
  cout << "FuelTankSize: " << getFuelTankSize() << endl;
  cout << "Type: " << GasVehicle::getType() << endl;    //resolve scope here
  cout << "Model: " << GasVehicle::getModel() << endl;  //resolve scope here
}
```